# C# ClickOnce Deployment Mapping Back to My Desktop Drive

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I created a WinForms application that includes code to find the user's desktop and perform 3 tasks:
1. Create a folder 
2. Read a .csv file
3. Output some data to a .csv file on the desktop.

I'm using the code below to find the user's desktop

```
    string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

I used the ClickOnce deployment to install the program to our network drive.  The program installs successfully, but Whenever I have someone attempt to run the program from their terminal, they get an error message that states "The directory name is invalid" and it references my desktop and not the user's.

How should I change my code or the deployment method so it references the user's desktop?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Can you clarify on exactly "when" this error is thrown ? Your questions talks about "someone attempt to install", but your error message references a code (which implies, exception is thrown at run time?). Please update the Question to make this clear.

Comment: @Znaneswar your answer wont work because the program is referencing a directory that is not part of the network location or the other user. if the file path is situated within the `\Users\` directory, i expect that will crash too.

Comment: @Subbu - I edited it for clarity.  You're correct the exception is thrown at run time.

Comment: when you say it referenced my desktop, do you mean the desktop of the pc used to develop the App or the desktop on the network drive?

Also, (dumb but have to check) is the network drive an actual drive on another machine or is it a drive on "your" pc that is shared to the network?

Comment: Yes, it referenced the desktop of the PC used to develop the application.  The network drive is an actual drive on another machine that we all have access to.

Answer (score 0):

If directory invalid try creating it
Try with this code

```
 string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); 
 string extension = ".log"; filePath += @"\Error Log\" + extension;
  if (!Directory.Exists(filePath)) { 
 Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change to my code and it worked as needed:

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```